# SQL Query Advice - Updating records based on duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm after some advice for a query I need to write that extends beyond my current SQL skills/capability.

The logic is as follows:

For each set of duplicate `devices_fk` in **SUBQUERY***, update the row(s) with the *earliest* `date_start` value to set `date_end=NOW()`. Only one record should remain, per `device_fk`, where `date_end IS NULL`.

Subquery:

```
SELECT 
    map_id, devices_fk, user_fk, date_start, date_end 
FROM 
    [users_devices_map] 
WHERE 
    date_end IS NULL 
    AND devices_fk IN (SELECT devices_fk 
                       FROM [users_devices_map] 
                       WHERE date_end IS NULL
                       GROUP BY devices_fk 
                       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY
    devices_fk ASC, date_start DESC
```

To assist in understanding my question, this is what subquery outputs:

[image: Output of Subquery]

After the above-described query is executed, the subquery should return no results (ie. because there are no duplicate `devices_fk` with a `NULL` `date_end`).

The end goal is to have only one row with a `NULL` `date_end` for each `devices_fk`, by setting an end date (`date_end`) for the earliest of the start dates (`date_start`) for that same device (`devices_fk`).

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: by earliest, did you mean the previous record of the duplicate row or the first record of the duplicate rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
;With cteDevicesMap  As
(
      SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY devices_fk ORDER BY date_start DESC) AS RN
      FROM [users_devices_map]
)
UPDATE [users_devices_map] SET date_end = GETDATE()
FROM cteDevicesMap WHERE RN > 1;
```

Now check records in your table.

```
SELECT * FROM [users_devices_map] WHERE date_end IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Have not tested this..

```
update a
set a.date_end = b.date_start
from [users_devices_map] a
join (select max(map_id) map_id, devices_fk, min(date_start) date_start from [users_devices_map] 
group by map_id, devices_fk) b on a.map_id <> b.map_id and a.devices_fk = b.devices_fk
where a.date_end is null
```